# Optimizing atomic compare_exchange_weak

Tags: c++, optimization, std

I'm trying to create a template to hold an arbitrary enum type (for type safety) and store them as shown in the following code segment:

```
enum my_flags : uint8_t {
    value = 0x01,
    foo = 0x02,
    bar = 0x04
}

template <class FlagType>
class atomic_flags {
    FlagType fetch_and_set(FlagType f) {
        //FlagType old; // <- Undefined behavior! At least in theory.
        FlagType old = flag_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // Correct, but takes two times longer.
        while(!flag_.compare_exchange_weak(old, static_cast<FlagType>(old | f))) {}
        return old;
    }

    std::atomic<FlagType> flag_;
};
```

The storing itself is trivial and not directly relevant. What I'm interested in are the two commented lines. The first one is by C++ Standard definition undefined behavior (UB). The second one is what I should use for correctness. But benchmarking shows that it's 2x times slower than the first variant. At the same time the first variant always produces the expected behavior, using the msvc compiler. (Probably because the compiler now doesn't have to load `old` twice, because this is done by `compare_exchange_weak` anyway.)

Now my question: **Is it possible to achieve the same performance without relying on UB?** (Yes, this is part of a performance critical section.)

As a side note. If I directly substitute `uint8_t` as a type and use the standard functions for `fetch_or` the performance is equivalent to the UB case. It's probably possible to try and substitute `FlagType` in the `flag_` definition directly through a type big enough to contain `FlagType` but this appears just as error prone to me.

***EDIT:***
This is the code I use for testing correctness as well as for benchmarking (only the `REQUIRE` statements will be left out in the benchmark.)

```
TEST_CASE( "Testing atomic_flags", "[atomic_flags]" ) {
    enum my_enum : uint8 {
        clear  = 0x00,
        first  = 0x01,
        second = 0x02,
        third  = 0x04,
        fourth = 0x08,
        fifth  = 0x10,

        all = first | second | third | fourth | fifth,
    };

    atomic_flags<my_enum> flag(clear);

    REQUIRE(flag.fetch_and_set(first) == clear);
    REQUIRE(flag.fetch_and_set(second) == first);
    REQUIRE(flag.fetch_and_set(fifth) == (first | second));
    REQUIRE(flag.fetch_and_set(third) == (first | second | fifth));
    REQUIRE(flag.fetch_and_set(fourth) == (first | second | third | fifth));
    REQUIRE(flag.fetch_and_clear(all) == all); // Note: fetch_and_clear removes a flag.
    REQUIRE(flag.load() == clear);
}
```

My benchmarking results are 40ns for UB and 75ns for correct per call.

Comment: You're defaulting to the sequentially-consistent version of both atomic ops, do you definitely need that degree of strictness? And, you're not re-loading `old` if the cas fails, which makes it unlikely to succeed on the next attempt.

Comment: I left out the memory order for clearness, but I'm using `std::memory_order_relaxed` for the load operation and for the exchange there is actually a function parameter so the user may change it. (Should I edit my question for more clarity on this point?) And the `old` parameter is updated by `compare_exchange_weak` every loop. It's passed as a reference.

Comment: Fundamentally, you have to make an initial guess as to what the old value was for your CAS. How you do that is up to you; is there a value that's going to be very likely in all cases? Go with that one. If you're always going to guess wrong, but are in low contention, then two loads is what you should expect. Your request for UB is essentially saying "I  don't even want to make a first guess, I just want to be totally wrong and go from there" which is actually worse than at least making an educated guess.

Comment: THAT is exactly the behavior i expected. But reality proves me wrong. Try executing this code with a print statement in a loop. At least for me (unless there is one of those spurious failures weak exchange may have) the loop is never accessed for single thread testing. (The benchmark called the function 6410215 times, and printed TWO print statements.)

Comment: Is the benchmark useful, given that it has UB? What does the generated code actually do?

Comment: I edited the post to show my test and benchmark code.

Comment: What is the timing if you initialize `FlagType old = clear;`?

Comment: In that case I get 90ns.

Comment: For your "undefined behavior" version to do better than initialization to any one of the flags, something is likely putting the actual `old` value in prior to the function call (perhaps retaining a value from a previous call, perhaps something in the benchmark validation code).  This is something that happens inside a tight benchmarking loop, but not in real life.

Comment: Notably, all your calls contain the true value of `old` as the right-hand operand of the equality comparison.  The compiler might easily be preloading that value into the same register that happens to be used for `old`.

Comment: And of course, your benchmark doesn't actually cause any contention, ever, so you are not really measuring the performance tradeoffs of interlocked access.  If I were the compiler and inlined that function call, the next thing I'd do it notice that the variable is a local whose address is not leaked to any other thread, therefore immediately rewrite the store-conditional loop to a simple non-threadsafe `old = flag; flag |= f; return old;`

Comment: BTW what compile options are you using with the benchmark? (particularly interested in optimization flags)

Comment: I used the default flags cmake sets for a release build in msvc. But your other comment got me on the right track. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the quick help in pointing out my possible errors.

The actual performance of those two versions are equivalent, but in the second case the compiler does not do all possible optimizations for some reason.

By wrapping every call of the `fetch_and_set` function in a `benchmark::DoNotOptimize()` statement, both cases peform equaly well (I'm using google microbenchmark lib, and this call avoids the return value being optimized away). Therefore the point of the original question is moot and the initialized value is obviously the correct choice.